# I am struggling to control the gravity of a textView inside my CardView items once I put it inside a GridView

Tags: android, kotlin, gridview, cardview

Below is a screenshot of my gridView currently: 
Even though I have centered the TextField inside the card, they are still pinned to the left. How do I fix this so that the Text is centered in the middle? It seems like once I add an item to a gridView, the gridView attributes overrule their children.

[image: Card Views inside GridView]

Here is my layout code:

**CARDVIEW**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    layout_height=""
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#E73737"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCategoryIcon"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvCategoryTitle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_translation_panel_loading" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCategoryTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivCategoryIcon" 
/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.CategoryViewFragment">

<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvCategories"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried `android:gravity="center"` inside your `TextView`

Comment: Add your `ImageView` and `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout` and place that `LinearLayout` inside the `CardView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:gravity="center"` in your textview like following.

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvCategoryTitle"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
     android:text="TextView"

     android:gravity="center" 

     android:textAlignment="center"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivCategoryIcon"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use relative layout insists of ConstraintLayout.

use center_horizontal to the text view=true

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this and change your constraint layout ?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCategoryIcon"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_translation_panel_loading" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCategoryTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivCategoryIcon"
                />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```